# Java Regexp to match words only (', -, space)

Tags: java, regex

What is the Java Regular expression to match all words containing only :

- From **a** to **z** and **A** to **Z**
- The **'** **-** **Space** Characters but they must not be in the beginning or the
  end.

*Examples*

- **test'test** match
- **test'** doesn't match
- **'test** doesn't match
- **-test** doesn't match
- **test-** doesn't match
- **test-test** match

Comment: At the very least post your examples of matches and non-matches.

Comment: edited with examples

Comment: You can use `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z'\s-]*[a-zA-Z]$` (will require at least 2 characters in input)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern: `^(?!-|'|\\s)[a-zA-Z]*(?!-|'|\\s)$`

Below are the examples:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = " abc";
String s3 = "abc ";
System.out.println(s1.matches("^(?!-|'|\\s)[a-zA-Z]*(?!-|'|\\s)$"));
System.out.println(s2.matches("^(?!-|'|\\s)[a-zA-Z]*(?!-|'|\\s)$"));
System.out.println(s3.matches("^(?!-|'|\\s)[a-zA-Z]*(?!-|'|\\s)$"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you mean the whitespace char it is: `[a-zA-Z ]`
So it checks if your string contains a-z(lowercase) and A-Z(uppercase) chars and the whitespace chars. If not, the test will fail

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

`/(\w{2,}(-|'|\s)\w{2,})/g`

You can take it for a spin on [Regexr.](http://regexr.com/3ghk4)

It is first checking for a word with `\w`, then any of the three qualifiers with "or" logic using `|`, and then another word. The brackets `{}` are making sure the words on either end are at least 2 characters long so contractions like `don't` aren't captured. You could set that to any value to prevent longer words from being captured or omit them entirely.

Caveat: `\w` also looks for `_` underscores. If you don't want that you could replace it with `[a-zA-Z]` like so:

`/([a-zA-Z]{2,}(-|'|\s)[a-zA-Z]{2,})/g`